# How to retrieve historical search volume data in google ad word api?

Tags: google-ads-api

I am retrieving search volume by below code but I want to get historic data for last 5 years

```
 $selector = new TargetingIdeaSelector();
  $selector->requestType = 'STATS';
  $selector->ideaType = 'KEYWORD';
  $selector->requestedAttributeTypes = array('KEYWORD_TEXT', 'SEARCH_VOLUME');
```

I know if I add **TARGETED_MONTHLY_SEARCHES** in requestedAttributeTypes i will be able to retrieve last 12 month data, but i want to retrieve last 5 years data.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I believe you can not access data older than 12 months, maybe you can use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36495388/casperjs-hangs-out-when-accessing-google-keyword-planner

Comment: Will it return more than 12 month data?

Comment: Read the question...

Comment: yes, I have read the question carefully - want to get more than 12 month of data.